# Changing Standard output in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to change standard output stream so that it is written to some file rather than console in Java ???

Comment: java YourClass > outputFile ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `System.setOut(PrintStream out);`

[Check out the API documentation for System.setOut().](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do.
To directly answer your question, you would do something like

```
System.setOut(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
```

However, I would use the logging framework for writing to a file. First, initialize your logger somewhere:

```
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("mylogfile.txt", true); // True to append to file, false to overwrite.
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
logger.addHandler(handler);
```

Then you can have a method you call every time you want to print something, like:

```
public void output(String message, boolean toConsole, boolean toFile) {
    if (toConsole) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    if (toFile) {
        m_logger.info(message); // Your instance variable of Logger.
    }
}
```

You could do this however you want, but that's one example. You could have toConsole and toFile simply be static booleans that you configure instead of specifying for each method call.

Answer (score 2):

`System.setOut(new PrintStream(file))`

But using logging approach is a much better way.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [System.setOut](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(you file name)));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.setOut()` to do that